# JQuery selector for each() to iterate through only the current level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here comes today's trivial problem.

I am parsing an XML file with JQuery. It contains a tree of several items called `<property>` which contain `<option>` elements. They define dropdown menus. Here is an example:

```
<property>
    <option>
        <text>option 1</text>
    </option>
    <option>
        <text>option 2</text>
    </option>
    <option>
        <text>option 3</text>
    </option>
</property>
```

This is pretty straightforward to parse, but sometimes another `<property>` is nested into an `<option>` because it defines a submenu which should only appear if the given option is selected:

```
<property>
    <option>
        <text>option 1</text>
    </option>
    <option>
        <text>option 2</text>
        <property>
            <option>
                <text>suboption 1</t
            </option>
            <option>
                <text>suboption 2</text>
            </option>
        </property>
    </option>
    <option>
        <text>option 3</text>
    </option>
</property>
```

These nested `<property>` elements may contain further `<property>` elements, and so on. Basically it's a tree structure.

The question is how can I use jQuery to collect the `<option>` elements from only a given level. If I do this...

```
$(xml).find('property').each(function () {
    var selector = $('<select></select>', {'id': $(this).attr('id')});
    $(this).find('option').each(function () {
        $(selector).append($('<option></option>', {'text': $(this).find('text').text()}));
    });
    $('#controls').append(selector);
});
```

... it will collect all `<option>` elements from the current level and all lower levels. Since I am referring to the current level as `$(this)` I have no idea how to tell JQuery to only collect them from the current level (the level of `$(this)`) and leave lower levels alone. Could someone please fix this gap in my jQuery knowledge? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery's `.children()` method as an alternative to `.find()`?  https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: It is doing the same. I could do:
`$(this).children('option').each(function () { });` but it does the same. Filters won't help much.

Comment: **$(this).children('option')** is not the same as **$(this).find('option')**.

Comment: Ah yes, this one worked. There was another bug which I haven't noticed: I should refer to `$(this).find('text:first').text()` instead of `$(this).find('text').text()` or it'll add all texts to the option. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome!  Converted my comments into an answer below.  :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I realized my commenting was looking more like answering.  Whoops.  :)

Consider using jQuery's [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method as an alternative to `.find()`.  That way you'll only traverse direct descendants.

```
function generateSelectElementFromXml(xml) {
  var selector = $('<select></select>', {'id': $(this).attr('id')});
  $(xml).children('property').each(function () {
    $(this).children('option').each(function () {
        $(selector).append($('<option></option>', {
          'text': $(this).children('text').text()
        }
      ));
    });
  });
  return selector;
}
```

Then you can generate a `<select>` element in your controls `<div>` like so:

```
$('#controls').append(generateSelectElementFromXml(xml));
```

Here's an example CodePen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAYQAV